# In MS Access when I run a select query my data type changes. How can I prevent this?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have 2 tables that are linked to 2 different Excel spread sheet. My primary key for table A is stored as a text in Excel therefore the data type in Access is Short Text. The foreign key in Table B is also stored as a text in Excel and shows up as a Short Text data type in Access.

When I run a select query from these table I get "Type mismatch expression" error. If I go back and look at Table A my primary key field has now changed to a Number data type. Therefore my tables will not properly relate or query together. How can I get my linked table to stop changing the data type when I run a query?

Comment: In my experience Access can sometimes behave strangely and "forget" stuff. I have previously had success with 1) removing the data sources, 2) making sure everything is correct in the data source and then 3) adding the sources again. In that order.

Comment: I had to wait to get access to the Excel files but it seems to be work now after removing and re-adding. I wish there was a way to prevent this error as I do not plan to maintain this database. Thanks for the help though Steffen!

Comment: Yeah it is really annoying. Haven't found a solution to this issue myself, but will keep a look out ;-)

Comment: If a different user has the excel workbook open while I try to run the query I still receive the error. I can only run the query if the linking document is closed.

Comment: Yes that is expected behavior, because when opening a spreadsheet in Excel, Excel puts a lock on the file (only one can edit a a time). Accessing the Excel file thru Access tries to put the file in edit mode, because you could do read/write thru Access - but Excel does not allow this behavior. Try going the other way around, you might get same result, except this time Access may be locking the file for edit instead of Excel (I can't remember for sure if this is the behavior of Access as well)